# Oracle to SQLServer conversion

Tags: sql-server-2008

I  have the following query in oracle so dont know how to convert into SQL Server.

```
WITH    start_date      AS
(
        SELECT  TO_DATE ( '01-Jan-2010'
                        , 'DD-Mon-YYYY'
                        )       AS start_date
        FROM    dual
)
SELECT    m.task_name
,         COUNT (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR (d.task_date, 'DD') = '01' THEN 1 END)       AS Day_1
,         COUNT (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR (d.task_date, 'DD') = '02' THEN 1 END)       AS Day_2
,         COUNT (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR (d.task_date, 'DD') = '03' THEN 1 END)       AS Day_3
...
,         COUNT (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR (d.task_date, 'DD') = '31' THEN 1 END)       AS Day_31
FROM      task_master   m
JOIN      task_detail   d       ON      m.task_id       = d.task_id
JOIN      start_date    s       ON      d.task_date     >=            s.start_date
                                AND     d.task_date     < ADD_MONTHS (s.start_date, 1)
GROUP BY  m.task_name
;
```

Comment: Oracle to oracle? Or to SqlServer?

Comment: Need to convert into SQLServer

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using

[DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to check the day of month (use d or dd)

and

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,'01-Jan-2010')
```

for the Date

and

[DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258267%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to add the date use `DATEADD (datepart ,number,date )`